# BIRT Bar Chart Color by Optional Y-Group

Tags: report, birt

I'm using BIRT Report Designer (seems to be version 0.0.0...) and I'm trying to change this bar graph so that the colors are based on the Y-Grouping rather than the x-axis category. That is, I want the skinny bars to be colored based on the Person they represent while the actual columns stay grouped by the category.

[Productive_Indirect_Time_Per_Person_Grouped_By_Category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I87Gp.jpg)

I feel like this should be a simple thing, but I haven't been able to find it anywhere.

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: @FannyV I want it to display like this kinda thing [link](http://www.ielts-exam.net/images/graphs/IELTS_Writing_Task_1_138.png) instead of coloring all the first ones blue, then all the next ones red, etc.

Comment: on the onRender Script, see the beforeDrawDataPoint( dph, fill, icsc ) & beforeDrawLegendItem( lerh, bounds, icsc ) methods.